# Why the last three digit of a sum are always 666?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I accidentally discovered that
$$\sum _{k=1}^{n} (2 k)!\equiv 666, \bmod 1000\land n\geq 7$$

If I consider odd numbers, last 3 digits are $646$. 
Taking only prime number gives $768$.

I can't prove it. Can someone please help?

Comment: Because you have a factorial.

Comment: Note that $16!$ is already divisible by $1000$.

Comment: @lulu I got it! Since sum up to n = 7 is 87,660,962,666 and all the other factorials like 16! and 18! have 000 as last digits, it remains 666. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As shown by @lulu, there is absolutely no magic.

For $n=7$, the sum turns out to be $87660962666$ where $666$ is purely accidental. For $n=8$ and following, the factorials end in $000$ so that the last digits remain.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(2*8)!=16!$
$=1000*16*3*14*13*12*11*1*9*8*7*6*3*2*1$ by factoring out the $4$, the $5$, the $10$, and the $5$ from the $15$.
So adding $16!$ or any multiple (like $(2*9)!=18*17*16!$) doesn't change the last three digits anymore.

Therefore, all you have to check is that $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^7}(2k)!$ ends in $666$. Factoring, this sum is $2*\left(1+3*4*\left(1+5*6*\left(1+7*8*\left(1+9*10*\left(1+11*12*\left(1+13*14\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)$, which reduces modulo $1000$ as follows:

$=2*\left(1+3*4*\left(1+5*6*\left(1+7*8*\left(1+9*10*\left(1+11*12*183\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)$

$\equiv2*\left(1+3*4*\left(1+5*6*\left(1+7*8*\left(1+9*10*\left(1+12*13\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)$ since $183*11=2013$

$=2*\left(1+3*4*\left(1+5*6*\left(1+7*8*\left(1+9*10*157\right)\right)\right)\right)$

$\equiv2*\left(1+3*4*\left(1+5*6*\left(1+7*8*\left(1+130\right)\right)\right)\right)$ since $10*157=1570$ and $9*570=5130$

$=2*\left(1+3*4*\left(1+5*6*\left(1+7*8*131\right)\right)\right)$

$\equiv2*\left(1+3*4*\left(1+5*6*\left(1+7*48\right)\right)\right)$ since $131*8=1048$

$=2*\left(1+3*4*\left(1+5*6*337\right)\right)$

$\equiv2*\left(1+3*4*\left(1+5*22\right)\right)$ since $6*337=2022$

$=2*\left(1+3*4*111\right)$

$\equiv2*\left(1+332\right)$ since $3*4*111=1332$ 
$=2*333=\boxed{666}$.